# Preferred Idiom for UIViewController XIBs

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

In most sample and generated examples, the structure of XIBs for UIViewController subclasses is:

- Placeholders

  - File's Owner = Class of UIViewController subclass
  - First Responder
- Objects

  - View (wired to view outlet of owner)

However this structure does not allow for previewing of layout: File's Owner does not support the attributes inspector to display "simulated metrics". In order use the attributes inspector for the view controller, the following XIB structure is necessary:

- Placeholders

  - File's Owner = Class of UIViewController subclass
  - First Responder
- Objects

  - **A UIViewController**

    - View (wired to view outlet of owner)

My question is: is there any reason not to do this? The containing UIViewController seems to be ignored when the XIB is loaded, so it seems to just do the job of a container for purposes of prototyping and previewing in the IB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However this structure does not allow for previewing of layout: File's Owner does not support the attributes inspector to display "simulated metrics".

Any root `UIView` instance does.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed that. (What an embarrassing first question. I'll vote that up as soon as I have the rep.)